Argument list too long: '/bin/sh' when executing "free -h"
Trying to invoke free -h command via subprocess call from Python 3.8.16 at end of test session on almalinux v8.9 OS.
def pytest_sessionfinish(session):
    cmd = "free -h"
    tlogger.debug(f"Executing: {cmd}")
    try:
        subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        msg = f"Proceeding after command failed: {cmd}\nSTDERR: {e.stderr.strip()}\nRETURN CODE: {e.returncode}"
        logger.warning(msg)

Command will sometimes cause [Errno 7] Argument list too long: '/bin/sh' error. When this happens, the error does not get caught by try/except and pytest session is immediately terminated.
I was able to log the error and traceback by initiating the pytest session from a script like shown below
try:
    pytest.main("pytest tests", plugins=[collector])
except Exception as e:
    logger.error("ERROR: Exception while executing pytest command: {}".format(e))
    logger.error(traceback.format_exc())

Why is this error occurring? How can I catch the error in the pytest_sessionfinish hook to continue pytest session? I don't want to rely on triggering pytest command through script to catch error.
Captured Logs when intiating pytest command from script:
2024-11-11 12:23:03 root DEBUG conftest Executing: free -h
2024-11-12 01:07:37 root ERROR main ERROR: Exception while executing pytest command: [Errno 7] Argument list too long: '/bin/sh'
2024-11-12 01:07:37 root ERROR main Traceback (most recent call last) 
  File "/data/repos/tests/main.py", line 43, in main
    pytest.main("pytest tests", plugins=[collector])
  File "/var/lib/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 175, in main
    ret: Union[ExitCode, int] = config.hook.pytest_cmdline_main(
  File "/var/lib/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 513, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self._hookimpls.copy(), kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/var/lib/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 120, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/var/lib/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 139, in _multicall
    raise exception.with_traceback(exception.__traceback__)
  File "/var/lib/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 103, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/var/lib/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 320, in pytest_cmdline_main
    return wrap_session(config, _main)
  File "/var/lib/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 308, in wrap_session
    config.hook.pytest_sessionfinish(
  File "/var/lib/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 513, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self._hookimpls.copy(), kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/var/lib/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 120, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/var/lib/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 156, in _multicall
    teardown[0].send(outcome)
  File "/var/lib/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/hpe/lego/_plugin/job_executor.py", line 128, in pytest_sessionfinish
    self.execute_job(job)
  File "/var/lib/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/hpe/lego/_plugin/job_executor.py", line 115, in execute_job
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 493, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long: '/bin/sh'


Maybe not related but always try to avoid shell=True. Instead make it cmd = ["free", "-h"] and  set shell=False.

Also, what are you hoping for get out of the program when it successfully executes free -h  since you don't take care of the returned CompletedProcess?

To echo the first comment, the shell=True is almost comically unnecessary here. See Actual meaning of shell=True in subprocess

I don't see any way that error could happen with cmd = "free -h".

This error usually happens when executing a command with a wildcard argument, when the wildcard matches thousands of filenames. It can't happen with just a single argument.

One possibility is that the process's environment is full. The environment (env variables etc) and argument list share memory space, and if the environment is taking all of it, even a tiny argument list might not fit.

You could test for the environment issue with something like: subprocess.run(["free", "-h"], check=True, env={}) to give a clean environment to the program.
